# Is there a way to make MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, and ActionListener to work at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, listeners

I've been working on a program, which uses the arrow keys to move a rectangle representing the player, and mouse movement and clicks to aim where the newly created shots go.

However, every time I hold down the mouse, the shots only travel in the direction of the point where the mouse was first pressed.

I know that events are normally handled in the EDT, but is there a way to check for these events at the same time using threads?

https://gist.github.com/BigHairyYak/4062e1341580b6a837c0

There's a link to the program - I'm new to sharing code, so I just uploaded the whole thing. Thanks in advance for any advice on the matter.

Comment: It sounds like you are not updating the latest known mouse location from MotionListener after you detect a mouse click but before you detect that it's unclicked. You should just store the state obtained each time a listener is called and use it later. Think about it this way, what is the difference between knowing the precise mouse position at the time a button is clicked, when the mouse position is effectively 99.9 percent in the same position?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html

Take a peek at this @user3919381

Comment: It sounds like your issue is only happening when you hold the mouse down. If so, try using the `MouseDragged` event in `MouseMotionListener`.

Comment: I've tried using MouseDragged and MousePressed, but in both instances the point of (mouseX, mouseY) which is (e.getX(), e.getY()) inside both of those methods, is always the same until the mouse is released. What I'm asking is how to make it constantly update, because it seems to only call one method at a time from MouseListener or MouseMotionListener.

Comment: Use MouseMoved and MouseDragged it worked for me!!!!!